# Is there a mathematical property that allows multiplication of two sets of polar coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What I am asking is NOT about complex numbers.A typical pair of real numbers can be represented as a location on the x, y plane in terms of polar coordinates. Looks like ( r1 theta1).

Is it meaningful to try to multiply two pairs.?
 Specifically does the expression (r1, theta1) ( r2, theta2) = ?  have meaning in real numbers.   Assume complex numbers do not exist.  Thank you  Maybe in wrong area. Sorry . Not sure which tag handles polar coordinates exclusively.

Comment: Could you explain more about why you are thinking about multiplying sets of coordinates? There might be more than one possible interpretation. A little background on where you came across this problem and what you need from it might help guide the answers.

Comment: thank you David.  I am learning complex numbers on U tube from Harvey Gross MIT ...they were filmed in the 60's.  He has the equation above equal to a pair of complex numbers. ! The rest I can do with complex numbers if  I assume he takes the equation I gave you above and converts it to mean complex numbers.  The reason I ask is the following.  If someone just writes down the equation I gave how do you know that is assumes it is a complex number or should you do what Ross Millikan has suggested below? ...which then would need to be proven ...see my point and my confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly define such a product.  I am not familiar with a definition.  One example would be to say $(r_1,\theta_1)(r_2,\theta_2)=(r_1r_2,\theta_1\theta_2)$.  This doesn't feel right because the $\theta$s are only defined up to $\bmod 2\pi$ and choosing different $\theta$ values for a given point will give different values to the product.  To make it useful, it has to fit with some of the rest of the structure of mathematics.  I don't know any way to do this, which may be why we don't have a standard definition.  Note that the usual multiplication based in complex numbers has nice properties:  it is commutative and associative, it gives the same complex number as a result regardless of which value of $\theta$ you use.

Comment: please see my comment above before I accept answer ...thank you Ross

Comment: $(r,\theta)$ is a way of representing a complex number.  There are other ways, such as $a+bi$.  We have defined how to multiply complex numbers, usually starting from the $a+bi$ representation and using the fact that we want commutativity, associativity, and distributivity to hold.  That forces us to the usual multiplication rule.  Then when we have numbers represented in $(r,\theta)$ we can ask what the multiplication rule should be for that representation.  We find we are forced to $(r_1,r_2,\theta_1+\theta_2)$.  If you are not viewing them as complex numbers, you can define it any way.

Comment: ahhh .....now I understand.  thank you . that cleared it up and now I can continue .